# unable to access apache server from browsers

Tags: apache-2.2, firewall, linux-networking

I have installed apache2 on linux server, listening to port 80. But, I am unable to connect to the server when trying from browser. But when I am trying with curl command,

```
curl < ip >:80
```

It gives me the desired response.

I thought this should be because of firewall rules. Not sure, but I tried listing the rules with below command but didn't get any rules.

command: `sudo iptables -L --line-numbers`

output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) num target prot opt source destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) num target prot opt source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) num target prot opt source destination
```

I am not sure whether this is the correct way for getting the firewall rules. Please help me out if this can be only because of firewall or some other issue might be there. Also, if firewall is the issue, then how to find out if it is blocking or not and how to remove the blocking?

Comment: If you can reach the web server with curl and not with browser that is not a firewall rules, also the rules you post allow anything to pass. Could you provide more information? Like, were you run curl command, locally/remote? Were the server is installed Physical/VM? What the apache2 configuration?

Comment: If you perform the command `curl < ip >:80`on the server itself and get response, that only means that the web server is up and running, it does not mean that there is not another firewall between your webbrowser and the server (or maybe your webbrowser is configured to use a proxy, etc. ect.)

Comment: server is not a VM, it is physical server. I tried curl, with same server as well as from other server but in same privatet network. But when I tried curl from another VM from google cloud, that is also not responding anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `nmap` to determine if the port is filtered or not, from you machine

```
sudo nmap -Pn -p 80 SERVERIP
```

this will report 'Open' or 'Filtered' or even 'Closed' but at least you'll know where you stand.

Comment: Hi Zaid, I tried this command on same server where apache is installed and also from other server which is present on same VPN. Got the response as "Open". But still I am not able to connect from my local machine. Any other solution or let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: can you try this command form your machine or a machine on the same network as you?

Comment: My local machine having windows OS. Not sure, how to run this command from windows.

Comment: I tried on some other Ubuntu machine. This is the response:80/tcp filtered http

Comment: filtered means a firewall has rejected the packets, I advise you to contact your system/network admin and present your findings to him/her.